# Why a sample space is a member of a collection of all the events?

Tags: probability-theory

I've just started learning the probability theory and I have a problem understanding the following point:

$$
\Omega \in \mathcal{F} 
$$

The $ \Omega $ is a set of all possible outcomes. For a single roll of a six sided die, we would have $ \Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} $.

The $\mathcal{F} $ is a set of zero or more outcomes. It is a subset of the sample space. So if we consider only even rolls, we would have $ \mathcal{F} = \{2, 4, 6\}. $

Now, how can a set of six elements ($\Omega$) be a member of a set ($\mathcal{F}$) whose elements are $2,4,6$?

Comment: You are confusing particular events (such as  rolling an even number, $\{2,4,6\}$) with the collection $\mathcal F$ of all possible events.

Comment: So,  is $\mathcal{F}$ (no more than?) the power set of $\Omega$?

Comment: I'm assuming there was a handwriting mistake somewhere along the line.  To start with, $\mathcal F$ is usually the set of all events, namely (in the finite case) the power set of $\Omega$.  So of course $\Omega\in\mathcal F$ and so on. In the classroom I'd soon segue to other, more complicated subfields of $\mathcal F$ , and maybe your question involves  some topic overlap-induced confusion  with such examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal F$ is not a subset of the sample space $\Omega$ but is a subset/subcollection of powerset $\wp(\Omega)$.

In your example (and lots of other cases) commonly $\mathcal F=\wp(\Omega)$.

Set $\{2,4,6\}$ is an element of $\mathcal F$ and these elements are called "events".

The mentioned set is/represents the event that an even number is thrown.

If the die is unbiased then $P(\{2,4,6\})=\frac12$.

Also $\Omega\in\mathcal F$ and this set is/represents the event that a number is thrown.

In fact in every probability space we have $\Omega\in\mathcal F$.

This with $P(\Omega)=1$.